# Eloquent not linking tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

So I've got 3 tables. But Laravel fails to link the tables to eachother, I feel like I'm missing a really small thing but I can't seem to find it.

**Controller**

```
$data = Item::all();
$clipper = $data->first();
dd($clipper->attributes());
```

**Item**

```
protected $table = 'item';
protected $primaryKey = 'item_id';
public $timestamps = false;

public function attributes() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Attributes', 'item_id');
}
```

**Atrributes**

```
protected $table = 'attributes';
protected $primaryKey = 'attr_id';
public $timestamps = false;

public function name() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Attributesname', 'name_id');
}
```

**Attributes Name**

```
protected $table = 'item_attributes';
protected $primaryKey = 'item_attr_id';
public $timestamps = false;
```

**Result of dd**

[image: Result of dd]

**Database design**

[image: Design of my database]

Comment: you dont know if it is as you haven't queried or loaded the relationship yet ... relationship methods return relationship type objects (query builders basically) they do not return the result of the relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel links relations fine, see you output parent model is the Item, related model is the Atribute, try this to see related data (not relation) :

```
$data = Item::all();
$clipper = $data->first();
dd($clipper->attributes);
```